# Icinga2 repository key id

Tags: repository, puppet, hiera, icinga

This is node.yaml file where i should state that i want to use Icinga2 repository. I have a problem with matching keys, i can't get through because i don't know how to get the right key id. And that why I am not sure about the location as well, but it should be good. I am using puppet and hiera, so this should be done only through this yaml file.

```
icinga2:
   location: 'http://packages.icinga.com/ubuntu/'
   repos: 'main'
     key:
      id: '*****'
      server: 'agent.puppetzone.com'
      source: 'http://packages.icinga.com/icinga.key'
```

Comment: Are you using the official module from Icinga? You need to specify.

Comment: I do, i solved the issue, I was using wrong repos, and the key was not on that location. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why is it flagged down? May I know so I would not repeat the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using puppet-icinga2 module.

There it is, (node.yaml file) I have used wrong repository with the wrong key id:

```
apt::sources:
  icinga2:
    location: 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/formorer/icinga/ubuntu'
    repos: 'main'
      key:
         id: '4A132479423673E80ACCA85420EEDAFD36862847'
         server: 'keyserver.ubuntu.com'
```